Why does the file path keep getting restored to the original one that I changed when I save a file in VSCode
I created a new directory called "pages" and then moved my "about.html" to it, but when I save the file the original "about.html" in my root directory is restored and all changes saved to it. How do I change the file path for all future changes to be saved to my new "about.html" in my pages directory?
I tried to change the symbolic path.your text

Reopen the file after moving. Or save-as to create a copy, then delete the original.

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.

You didn't say how you moved the file.
